# User_status returns data empty for SOME users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have user_status permissions for one of our apps. Graph API 2.2 is being used to get user statuses (https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/feed?access_token=".$access_token). It returns empty data sets for SOME users (I get public profile info for these users but not status data). The app is live and the review team has granted permissions for user_status and user_likes. (user_status is passed to the scope). Is this a bug or User_status is dependent on some other permission? Why does it happen for some users and not all?

Comment: [Debug the access token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) for these users (or check `/me/permissions`), to see whether those users actually granted the permission.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe mentioned, you should inspect the Access Tokens with `/me/permissions` to see if they really contain the `user_status` permission.

I wonder why you're using `/me/feed` instead of `/me/statuses`. Maybe this has an effect as well.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_status
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/statuses/